# How many ways are there to fill this square?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to fill a $3*3$ square that consecutive numbers come next to each other.By counting cases and using symmetry I got $40$ cases.Didn't I have a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so you need a directional path visiting all squares.

Well, it's pretty obvious you can't begin in any of the squares in the middle of a side, for you cN't complete a path that way, so you either start in the middle or in a corner.

If you start in the middle, you can go in one of 4 directions, after which you turn clockwise or counterclockwise, and the rest is forced. So that's 8 possibilities.

If you start in a corner, you can do an 'S' or a 'Z', or do a clockwise or counterclockwise 'V' followed by one of two possibilities (one is a spiral inwards that ends in the middle), or start with one of two small 'L's after which the rest is forced. So, for each corner, you get 8 possibilities, for a total of 32 possibilities.

So yes, I get 40 as well!